# Codename name iOS and Android build Error

Tags: java, codenameone

Sending an iOS and  Android build results in a Jar size limit reached for free account but I am currently using a Pro subscription. What is the problem.
[image: Subscription Page]

[image: Android Build]

[image: iOS build]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're logged in as the pro user on this machine. Open up regedit and search for `codenameone` and `codename1`. Delete everything you find and try sending the build again. It should force a re-login.